# Authorisation strategy for a first-party express based node API

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm tackling the design of my first API and am struggling somewhat with authorisation concepts - I was hoping some kind people could give me some advice!

What I'm building:

- An API that will eventually be accessed by third party apps and a mobile app.
- A web-based 'client' (first-party single page app) that will use the API. (Should this first-party app be 'a part' of the API, or a completely separate node app?)

Technology I plan to use:

- Node
- Express
- Passport
- Mongodb with Mongoose

I'm not wed to express or passport, they just seem like the best options and are well documented - bit I wouldn't want a potential solution to be dismissed because of alternative dependencies. Same with Mongoose, I actually prefer the look of Monk (or even just Mongojs), but every tut seems to use mongoose, so seems like the safest option for a node beginner.

Authenticating a user is simple enough (I've gone through the fantastic [Beer Locker tutorial](http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/05/02/building-restful-apis-with-node/)), what I'm struggling with is ongoing authorisation. Naturally I don't want the user to have to input a username and password with every request they make - should this information be stored locally and sent with every request? (if so, how? I can't find any info on handling an API with a session) or should I be working with tokens of some sort? The small amount of reading I did on 'Digest' authorisation (including the Beer Locker tutorial follow-up) made it seem like it had security issues, at least with the Passport implementation (this I don't fully understand, but seems to relate to hashing passwords, which passport doesn't do as standard, and only MD5 is supported even if it's added?).

I have built a working API that I can authorise with 'Basic' (directly, through Postman), so I have the foundations in place - authorisation works, I just need the tools to take that to the next step and add sessions into the mix!

I've been trying to get my head around this for a couple of days now, but I fear I'm too stuck in a more traditional local web-app workflow - the whole API thing is throwing me somewhat.

Any help is hugely appreciated, even if it's just pointing me at an appropriate tutorial - the above set of requirements must be quite common!

Answer (score 1):

I have come accross this problem too...

I can only recommend doing this for the beginning:
http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

tell me if it helped :)

Comment: That looks like a solid tutorial - will the fact that it's for a 'local app', rather than using an API be an issue? I have a feeling I'm over thinking it…

Comment: This tutorial is not for a local app.. it leads you through the steps of creating an authentication API with node > express > passport---> i thought thats what you needed?

Comment: Ah, I may have misread/misunderstood - if that's the case then it'll be perfect! I'm just glancing over it now - will report back :)

Comment: HAHA, its probably the title: "getting started and local" -> local here means that you have your OWN authentication strategy (called localStrategy in the tut) next to FB, twitter and other strategies. I have looked all over the web and this is the best i ever found... I built a whole authentication setup with this tutorial

Comment: I dunno, I've just skimmed through the whole thing and don't see how I could take the learnings over to an API model (it's not RESTful at all from what I can see), what that tutorial builds is just a standard web app, there are no CRUD calls pushing the data back and forth from a separate service. This tut from the same site (http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular) seems more appropriate, but doesn't cover authorisation :/

Comment: What this tutorial does is build up an authorization that checks if a user is authorized on every route its applied on... these Routes can be defined with the typical CRUD way by using Express for exapmle app.get('/USER', localStrategy, function(){ code here });app.post('/USER' .... and so on... this way you set up CRUD / REST api

Comment: so basicly the authorization is actually independent of your REST API built with express... it can be applied to its Routes... if you read through the tut more carefuly you will see this :)

Comment: I think that makes sense, but would mean building the app INTO the API? What happens when I build the mobile app and it needs to perform the same authentication, but running as a 'third-party' app? (I may be misunderstanding something/not getting it - forgive me if that's the case - it has been a common theme over the past few days!)

Comment: I suppose my point is that that's all still 'internal' authentication isn't it? If I wanted to run the web app and the API on different servers, that tut isn't applicable (right?). i.e. it's not really a client for the API, that's just a web app.

Comment: you have a client (or what ever) firing requests to your API... your api checks if the requesters session is authorized and responds with the data.... anyone can connect to your api.. its a session based authentication

Comment: I think I'm maybe just over (or under!) thinking it - I'm going to go through the tutorial :) Thanks for your patience.

Comment: The API allows you to connect to the server from anywhere! :) for the authorization you will need some kind of session handling on the client side. So if your client is in the Browser this shouldnt be a problem at all...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have done the authentication and the only thing you have to do now is store somewhere that the current user is authenticated, his name, roles etc to use later with other requests. In the Passport you will do it in [the function callback](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) (instead of the "If this function gets called..." comment).

Now you have to decide, you have two options:

1. Store the user information (name, roles etc.) on your server (in a session) and give the user some long code which will identify his session for the next requests

   - to store the information on your server you may use for example the [express-session middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)
   - it would be probably best to save the session identifier in a cookie, but read some security issues before
2. Give the user something that would prove to you he/she is authenticated and which name, roles etc. he/she has

   - you can generate a token, that contains the user information (name, roles etc.) that the user will send with every request. to know this token is legit, you will have to sign it. more on this is on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and you can use [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) middleware.
   - you dont have to care about storage of session with this one
   - the token can be placed to a cookie too, but same security issues apply. it is still considered better that localstorage (more [here](https://medium.com/@saivicky2015/why-jwt-shouldnt-be-stored-in-local-storage-aa9aeacc46a0))